# Как парсить информацию со всех регионов, если мой браузер настроен только на мой регион?

Tags: python, парсер

Всем привет,

изучать python начал недавно и сейчас набираюсь опыта в парсинге. Посмотрел разные видео и решил попробовать создать парсер для auto.ru (достаточно банально, но полезно в моей работе)

Вот ссылка на сайт: https://auto.ru

Хочу, чтобы выбирал новые автомобили, любую марку, затем любую доступную модель, вставлял соответствующую ссылку в 'URL' и выгружался список с интересующей меня информацией. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой: учел пагинацию, но при проверке заметил, что количество страниц при парсинге отличается от реального количества страниц на сайте (у меня парсится меньше)
Выяснил, что выгружаются только автомобили моего региона ("Москва"), а я хочу, чтобы выгружался "Любой регион", то есть все автомобили (кнопка в правом верхнем углу).

Но никак не могу разобраться, как правильно записать это в параметры и в параметры ли вообще.

Если кто подскажет, буду очень благодарен

Код вот:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL='https://auto.ru/cars/new/group/audi/a6/21210593-21210635/'
HEADERS={'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.1 Safari/605.1.15', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r=requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_pages_count(html):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    pagination=soup.find_all('a', class_='Button Button_color_whiteHoverBlue Button_size_s Button_type_link Button_width_default ListingPagination-module__page')
    if pagination:
        return int(pagination[-1].get_text())
    else:
        return 1

def parse ():
    html=get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code==200:
        pages_count=get_pages_count(html.text)
        print(pages_count)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

Comment: у вас из get_pages_count(html) возвращается что-то, кроме 1? у меня при запуске в soup - `<title>Доступ заблоковано</title>`... наверное, не роcсийский ip потому что...

Comment: @Jack_oS, у меня возвращается '7', так как для моего региона доступно семь страниц на сайте, в то время как для всех регионов '11'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте передать все заголовки которые есть. Для этого нужно зайти в код элемента -> network -> потом не выходя из кода элемента выбрать все регионы. У вас перезагрузится страница и покажутся много файлов, нужно выбрать первый и нажать Headers. И там покажутся все заголовки, которые передаются. Один из них, скорее всего, будет отвечать за выбранное местоположение, надо просто в запросе передать все заголовки.

Comment: каким образом user-agent может быть привязан к региону?

Comment: @Lamer на всякий случай попробовал, но с твои вариантом выдал ошибку. Исправил, но все-равно не помогло. 

При первичном входе с любого браузера мне автоматически предлагает регион "Москва + 200 км" и любой другой вариант уже сохраняется в cookies. Можно ли при парсинге обращаться к cookies?

Comment: Можно попробовать передать все заголовки которые есть.
Для этого нужно зайти в код элемента -> network -> потом не выходя из кода элемента выбрать все регионы. У вас перезагрузится страница и покажутся много файлов, нужно выбрать первый и нажать Headers. И там покажутся все заголовки, которые передаются. Один из них, скорее всего, будет отвечать за выбранное местоположение, надо просто в запросе передать все заголовки.

Comment: @Lamer, получилось, как раз был заголовок, отвечающий за cookies. Спасибо!